# Send status from controls to framework

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns

I've UI Controls that are inherit from abstract control,
in the abstract control I've method that every control should extend which is called isValid that return true/false and I need (as framework) 
to know if to mark it on red (non-valid case),there is a design pattern which I should use in this case to help me with this or which approach should I use ?

Comment: Sounds pretty solid to me. You may want to post your code over on [codereview.se] to get a solid review.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - Thanks but I want to find the right approach before Im going to implement it :) any suggestion ?

Comment: There is no need to wedge a design pattern in here -- this is straightforward polymorphism.

Comment: @dbugger - can you provide example in Javascript?

Comment: @Mark since this is javascript question, are you using pure javascript or some framework? Because unlike OOP languages, JS inheritance is prototype based, not class based, but many frameworks are circumventing this to an extent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are developing in pure Javascript (i.e. no React or Angular or jQuery), I would use the existing [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) available in the DOM elements to update on changes.

Abstract parts:

```
// Create the basic AbstractControl class.
var AbstractControl = function() {

}

// Virtual methods.
AbstractControl.prototype.isValid = function() {
    throw new Error('Not implemented.')
}

AbstractControl.prototype.paintGreen = function() {
    // Valid case.
    throw new Error('Not implemented.')
}

AbstractControl.prototype.paintRed = function() {
    // Invalid case.
    throw new Error('Not implemented.')
}

// Function Update verifies the validity of the control and calls
// the valid or invalid case accordingly.
AbstractControl.prototype.update = function() {
    if (this.isValid()) {
        this.paintGreen();
    } else {
        this.paintRed();
    }
}
```

And an example concrete control class:

```
// Class for an email input text field, receives a DOM element.
var EmailField = function(element) {
    AbstractControl.call(this, AbstractControl);
    this.element = element;
    // Listens for change events on the element and updates
    // the valid/invalid status.
    this.element.addEventListener("change", this.update.bind(this));
}

// Setup inheritance.
EmailField.prototype = Object.create(AbstractControl.prototype);
EmailField.prototype.constructor = EmailField;

// Implement virtual methods.

EmailField.prototype.isValid = function() {
    return this.element.value.indexOf("@") >= 0;
}

EmailField.prototype.paintGreen = function() {
    alert("Email correct. Proceed.")
}

EmailField.prototype.paintRed = function() {
    alert("Email Incorrect! May not proceed.")
}
```

Final usage:

```
new EmailField(document.getElementById("emailfield"));
```

And it would `alert` on every change depending on the field contents. You can change the `alert` to instead color the elements (as indicated in the function name), or display some icon or tooltip.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/surj64vy/ (using more events to capture changes in realtime, and literally painting the field instead of alerting)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question 100%. Does this answer help?

Comment: 1+ Thanks I guess that this is more or less.2 questions 1.How  can I throw event from the concrete class that emails not valid? 2. I try to use it in jsFiddlle and it doesnt work for me can you please send it as jsBIn/fiddle... or something ? I want to test it Thanks!

Comment: 1. The `update` method is already called for each change, where you can respond to the event. 2. Sure, here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/surj64vy/

Comment: Thanks a lot, Assume that I dont working with the Dom(which I not), there is a way to use it?im not working with angular or React etc...